# how sum in entity manager asp.net models

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to calculate  sum from table somme the varaible sum  in date2  from entity manager from model in asp.net   i use models and entity manager so i need a response like this in structure i mean that i want to have a response in table tab

and this the code that i want

```
 DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2015, 7, 15);
 for (int i = 0; i < differenceInDays; i++)
 {
     tab[i] = db.NXT_ADMISSON
              .Count(NXT_ADMISSON => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(NXT_ADMISSON.DAT_ADM) == date2.Date 
                  && NXT_ADMISSON.ID == 2);
     date2 = date2.AddDays(1);
 }
```

I want a code like this can someone help me to fix this

Comment: i can't understand what are you trying to acheve. What you want to get in the end?

Comment: TAB[i] =SUM NXT_ADMISSON.NBREAD  from model NXT_ADMISSON in condition  NXT_ADMISSON.DAT_ADM) == date2.Date

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct that's what you looking for:

```
tab[i] = db.NXT_ADMISSON
            .Where(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DAT_ADM) == date2.Date)
            .Sum(x => x.NBREAD);
```

Comment: error appered  you can't convert type 'int?' to int  can you help me to fix this

Comment: int tab  and i need a int